# Creating menu list in PHP: from nested list to multidimensional array and return

Tags: php, list, drop-down-menu, multidimensional-array, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to create a menu from a list with possible sub-lists.
From a simple  I want to create a compatible bootstrap menu
So from a code like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2
    <ul>
      <li>Sublink A</li>
      <li>Sublink B</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Link 3
    <ul>
      <li>Sublink C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'll have to create this:

```
array(
  [0] => array(
    [id]       => 1,
    [nome]  => 'Link 1',
    [parent] => NULL,
  ),
  [1] => array(
    [id]       => 2,
    [nome]  => 'Link 2',
    [parent] => NULL,
  ),
  [2] => array(
    [id]       => 3,
    [nome]  => 'Sublink A',
    [parent] => 2
  ),
  [3] => array(
    [id]       => 4,
    [nome]  => 'Sublink B',
    [parent] => 2
  ),
  [4] => array(
    [id]       => 5,
    [nome]  => 'Link 3',
    [parent] => NULL
  ),
  [5] => array(
    [id]       => 6,
    [nome]  => 'Sublink C',
    [parent] => 3
  )
)
```

And finally, get back this one:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a class="primary" href="link_1.html">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link 2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="sublink_a.html">Sublink A</a></li>
      <li><a href="sublink_b.html">Sublink B</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link 3</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="sublink_c.html">Sublink C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Conditions are:
if

has children  has href="#", add class dropdown-toogle and data-toggle="dropdown";
child  has class "dropdown-menu";
if

hasn't parent add class "primary" to

I use this code, but it's only for a simple list, not nested lists.

```
<?php
$currentPage = "";
$contents = "<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
</ul>";

// remove width, height, style
$contents = preg_replace('/(width|height|style|target)="[^"]+"/i', "", $contents);
// remove spaces form li
$contents = str_replace(array('<li >',' <li >'),"<li>",$contents);
// remove ul/ol tag and tabs
$contents = str_replace(array('\t','<ul>','<ul >','</ul>','<ol>','<ol >','</ol>'),"",$contents);
$arrNavTopList = explode("\n",trim($contents));
echo "<h4>Array:</h4>\n";
print_r($arrNavTopList);
echo "<hr>\n<h4>List:</h4>\n";
$totNavTopList = count($arrNavTopList);
if($totNavTopList>0){
  echo '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">'."\n";
  $countNtL=1;
  foreach($arrNavTopList as $pagename) {
    $pagename = str_replace("\t","",$pagename);
    preg_match_all("(<li>(.*?)</li>)", $pagename, $arrLinkList);
    $linktopage = $arrLinkList[1][0];
    if(
      strtolower($linktopage)==strtolower(str_replace("_"," ",$currentPage)) ||
      strtolower($linktopage)=="home" && !(strpos($currentPage,"^")===FALSE)
    ) {
      $active=' class="active"';
    } else {
      $active='';
    }
    echo '<li'.$active.'>';
    if (strstr($linktopage,"http") || strstr($linktopage,"target")) {
      $linktopage = preg_replace('/(style|target)="[^"]+"/i', "", $linktopage);
      $linktopage = str_replace('<a','<a rel="external nofollow" class="_blank"',$linktopage);
      echo $linktopage;
    } else {
      if(strtolower($linktopage)=="home" || strtolower($linktopage)=="home page") {
        echo '<a href="/">'.htmlentities($linktopage).'</a>';
      } else {
        echo '<a href="'.str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($linktopage)).'">'.htmlentities($linktopage).'</a>';
      }
    }
    echo '</li>'."\n";
    $countNtL++;
  }
  echo '</ul>'."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: as @Soundz mentionned you have to work more before posting that kind of question, there are tons of ways to implement what you want. I would use nested foreach with preg_match or something like that.

Comment: @Johnride what a nice way to express for what I only have harsh words for. Topic: How about a object which assembles it?

Comment: Try it at least, dont be lazy, here nobody write a complete code for anybody, somehow I would use recursivity.

Comment: I wrote a code that changes a simple list in a list with links, but I need something different. That's why I asked here without posting any kind of code. I do not have a code that does the extra step and did not want to write too much about the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Traverse an elements children and collect those nodes that
 * have the tagname specified in $tagName. Non-recursive
 *
 * @param DOMElement $element
 * @param string $tagName
 * @return array
 */

 //from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3049677/1596547

function getImmediateChildrenByTagName(DOMElement $element, $tagName)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($element->childNodes as $child)
    {
        if($child instanceof DOMElement && $child->tagName == $tagName)
        {
            $result[] = $child;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2
    <ul>
      <li>Sublink A</li>
      <li>Sublink B</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Link 3
    <ul>
      <li>Sublink C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>");

//from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953808/1596547
# remove <!DOCTYPE 
$doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild);            

# remove <html><body></body></html> 
$doc->replaceChild($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $doc->firstChild);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ul');
$parentitems = getImmediateChildrenByTagName($elements->item(0),'li');
$elements->item(0)->setAttribute ('class' , 'nav navbar-nav');
foreach ($parentitems as $parentitem)
{
    if($parentitem->childNodes->length > 1) {

        $parentitem->setAttribute ('class' , 'dropdown' );
        $link = $doc->createElement('a',$parentitem->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $link->setAttribute ('class' , 'primary dropdown-toggle' );
        $link->setAttribute ('href' , '#');
        $link->setAttribute ('data-toggle','dropdown');
        //$parentitem->nodeValue = null; 
        $old = $parentitem->childNodes->item(0);
        $parentitem->replaceChild($link,$old);

        $parentitem->childNodes->item(1)->setAttribute ('class' , 'dropdown-menu' );
        $submenuitems = getImmediateChildrenByTagName($parentitem->childNodes->item(1),'li');

        foreach($submenuitems as $submenuitem)
        {
            $link = $doc->createElement('a',$submenuitem->nodeValue);
            $link->setAttribute ('href' , $submenuitem->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue.'.html');
            $submenuitem->nodeValue = null; 
            $submenuitem->appendChild($link);
        }   


    }
    else 
    {
        $link = $doc->createElement('a',$parentitem->nodeValue);
        $link->setAttribute ('class' , 'primary' );
        $link->setAttribute ('href' , $parentitem->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue.'.html');
        $parentitem->nodeValue = null; 
        $parentitem->appendChild($link);
    }


}   

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

other answers used:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953808/1596547
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3049677/1596547